# Aligning words on the center line in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I'm looking for a way to better align text of different font sizes in MS Word. I can center it in the middle both vertically and horizontally in a cell/box, but I'd like to have the words sitting not on the bottom line (1st pic), but on the center line (2nd pic) without messing with various boxes for each font size.
[image: Actual]

[image: Desired]

Comment: I think you need to adjust the position for each word individually by more manual work. Select each word, right click and choose Font > Position > Lowered or raised with different numbers. Try to keep the center of the words on a horizontal line as possible.

Comment: It's not ideal, but for that example you could use a 1-row, 3-column table  with no borders with each word in a cell. Use @center@ vertical alignment for each cell (and possibly right alignment for the left cell and left alignment for the right cell). Then modify the horizontal cell layout to adjust the spacing between the words.

Comment: It's about book's spine, so it already is in a text box, split, rotated etc, to add more steps with tables or more boxes wouldn't work really well. But font position proved to be perfect for that, thanks Emily.